# Not able to uninstall VS 2013 professional with update 3

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to UNINSTALL VS - 2013 professional but I am not able to do so. Error I am getting is `"Visual Studio Core features fatal error during installation"`

When I check log file I get this message inside. after long list of text I find this somewhere in the log file

```
[11DC:14D4][2017-03-28T11:44:48]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (vs_professionalcore) failed: Error Message Id: 1305 ErrorMessage: Error 1305.Error reading from file C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CommandLine\v4.0_12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CommandLine.dll.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.
[13DC:1608][2017-03-28T11:46:08]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to uninstall MSI package.
[13DC:1608][2017-03-28T11:46:08]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
```

Kindly tell me how to fix it. I want to uninstall VS. Please help.

Comment: Refer to the error message, make sure your current account has the administrator right and check the permission of the specified DLL file, right click this file and give the full control permission to your current account and temporarily disable any antivirus, uninstall VS again. You can also have a try with VisualStudioUninstaller tool: https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller

Comment: Visual Studio Uninstaller worked like a charm. I had given all hope. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction. If you can put this as an answer I will accept it so that it help other too. Many thanks.

Comment: I'm so glad to hear that your issue is solved by VisualStudioUninstall tool and I already added a reply with this workaround :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clean up and delete Preview, RC and final releases of Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2015, as well as early previews of Visual Studio 2017, you can have a try with the VisualStudioUninstall tool: https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller